# Youtube settings (language, new layout, autoplay) reset once in a while

Tags: youtube, cookies, google-chrome-canary

Every once in a while my settings from youtube just dissappear and revert back to normal(?). My autoplay gets turned off and the new (experimental) layout resets or the dark theme in the new (experimental) layout gets disabled. Also the language turn back to a default based on IP, I guess.

Is this issue cookie based and can I somehow prevent it or check whether these cookies are part of the problem?

Or is it another sort of problem?

I am using Google Chrome Canary 65.0.3319.0 and I do not use any extension affecting youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `AdBlock` extension with `Adblock Plus` fixed the issue for me.